# Google AppEngine Flex Spamming Liveness and Rediness Check

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to debug 502 errors coming out of the nginx container with my AppEngine Flex setup.

I noticed that the logs indicate liveness and rediness checks being spammed very rapidly (see attached).

For clarification this is currently running a single instance in manual_scaling mode.

check_interval_sec is set for 30s on liveness_check and 5 sec on rediness_check.

Can anyone provide insight into what is going on here?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you setup [readiness and liveness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#liveness_path) too aggressively in your app.yaml. Please keep in mind that the checks works for every instance so if you have a lot of instances, it will occur frequently.

If you only have one instance setup, then the behavior contradict what the documentation described. Please file an issue with us on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case.  The above behavior is observed with:

manual_scaling
  instances: 1

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 5

liveness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 30

I would expect to see 1 entry every 5 seconds.

Comment: If you only have one instance, then the documentation does describe a behavior that's different than what you observed. It's likely an issue we will need to investigate. Please file an issue with us on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). I will edit my answer.